# Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: Error while launching browser

Tags: java, browser, selenium, selenium-rc

I initialize the selenium like

---

```
public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
     setUp("http://localhost/", "*firefox");
    }
```

---

and I write my test in the method like

---

```
public void testUntitled() throws Exception
{   
    boo();
    foo();
}
```

---

But it gives error like

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: Failed to
 start new browser session: Error while launching browser 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:89) 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:123)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase.setUp(SeleneseTestBase.java:104) 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.setUp(SeleneseTestCase.java:78)
at ComserTest_v2.setUp(ComserTest_v2.java:12) 
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:212)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) 
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)

Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Failed to start     
new browser session: Error while launching browser 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.throwAssertionFailureExceptionOrError(HttpCommandProcessor.java:97) 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.doCommand(HttpCommandProcessor.java:91)
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.getString(HttpCommandProcessor.java:262) 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.HttpCommandProcessor.start(HttpCommandProcessor.java:223) 
at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:81)...19 more
```

I could not find a solution myself and in google results. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Does *http://localhost/* work from your normal browser? Any port required?

Comment: http://localhost/ works well in my browser. There is no need for a port.

Comment: did you configure a firefox profile for selenium? FF only allows 1 instance per profile, if you use the same profile as an opened firefox selenium will not work

Answer (score 2):

Firefox only allows one instance of each profile. If you did not conigure anything for it and your firefox browser is open when starting the test. Firefox blocks selenium from using it.

Configure a profile in Firefox and you can configure selenium to use a ff profile

when you run Selenium Server, run with the server with 
command-line option -firefoxProfileTemplate "path to the profile"

(in case you didn't configured that)

[Configuring profiles in FF](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/managing+profiles)

Comment: I'm running tests on Ubuntu and I really do not know what is the Firefox profile and what is the path to that. I tried "java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate /etc/firefox-3.0" in terminal when I starting the Selenium server, and I close firefox before starting test but It still gives the same error.

Comment: if you start firefox with "-p" option you can access the profilemanager, "-p nameofprofile" option starts FF with the profile named as nameofprofile.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case as Selenium makes a copy of the FF profile and runs with that. You might encounter locking issues during the copy though.

Answer (score 1):

I keep having the same issue and have fixed it each time by updating my version of Selenium server to the latest version.  It seems that every time Firefox releases a new update it stops old versions of Selenium server from working!