# Selenium - Failed to Start Browser Session - Access Denied - XP

Tags: java, windows-xp, selenium

I'm getting the following error when starting up Selenium on XP

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Could not start Selenium session: Failed to start new browser session: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox (Access is denied)
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of stating the obvious, but it looks like Selenium is trying to read/write a Firefox profile but the system is blocking it. This could be because the Selenium user doesn't have appropriate security permissions, or possibly something else is locking access to a profile file.

You could try running the [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tools to identify what is getting in the way.

Firefox can block access to profiles to Selenium during the copy process, as is [mentioned in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289227/could-not-start-selenium-session-failed-to-start-new-browser-session-error-whil/3289522#3289522).

You may also want to [refer to the Selenium documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.html#specifying-the-firefox-profile) in regards to profile handling:

> Firefox will not run two instances
>   simultaneously unless you specify a
>   separate profile for each instance.
>   Selenium-RC 1.0 and later runs in a
>   separate profile automatically, so if
>   you are using Selenium 1.0, you can
>   probably skip this section. However,
>   if you’re using an older version of
>   Selenium or if you need to use a
>   specific profile for your tests (such
>   as adding an https certificate or
>   having some addons installed), you
>   will need to explicitly specify the
>   profile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting Firefox with the actual path to the Firefox browser? If you set Chrome as the target browser you should be able to avoid this.